# How can i scale two inline buttons to device width in jquerymobile?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

How can i scale two inline buttons to device width in jquerymobile.

```
<a href="#faq" data-role="button" data-inline="true">FAQ</a>
<a href="#help" data-role="button" data-inline="true">HELP</a><br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the **ui-grids**

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
<div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#faq" data-role="button">FAQ</a>
</div>
<div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#help" data-role="button">HELP</a>    </div>
</div><!-- /grid-a -->
```

Comment: tried but it just seperates them, i want to scale each to device width.

Comment: You want them 100% each? or both on one line with 50%?

Comment: i want both on one line each with 50% of device width.

Comment: ui-grids automaticallly set width to 50% (in this case, there are grids with more elements). What do you see instead? try taking out the "data-inline" attribute

Comment: it Worked without using inline tag.

Answer (score 2):

try with simple css

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}
```

or if you want each button to be the whole screen width use `width: 100%`.